# select id with a certain condition and measure average of the values of these ids in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I wish to select ids and take average of ids by a certain condition.  I'd like to measure the average of all the ids who had at least 1 time a particular factor

```
 mdf <- data.frame (id =c(1,2,3,2,1,2), 
factor= c("a","b","a","a","b" ,"a") , value = c(4,0,5,2,3,6))



   id factor value
1  1      a     4
2  2      b     0
3  3      a     5
4  2      a     2
5  1      b     3
6  2      a     6
```

For instance, I want average of ids who had `b`  as factor, id 1 and 2 had `b` as a factor at list one time, So' my code should extract the values of id 1 and id 2 and measure their average  (4 + 0 + 2 + 3 + 6) / 5 = 3. Note that id 3 never had `b`, so it is excluded from the calculation. 
so my ideal output will be

```
factor  avg
a      3.33
b      3
```

Comment: akrun, id 3 never had b, so it is excluded from the calculation, we take average of ids who had at least one time b in their factor. Please let me know if it is not clear, I'll give more example

Comment: Yes, for measuring average, I took the average of all the values by id 1 and id 2, since id 3 never had b, I excluded the value for id 3.

Comment: That's correct, but I have many factors, I can not  measure the value for each of them separately, I'd like to automatically do for all the factors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128520/discussion-between-akrun-and-mfr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After converting the `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT(mdf)`), we loop through the `unique` elements of 'factor', grouped by 'id', `if` `any` of the 'factor' have that particular element, subset the data.table (`.SD`), get the `mean` of the 'value' and the `unique` 'factor' element as a 2 column 'data.table' and `rbind` the `list` elements.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mdf)
rbindlist(lapply(unique(mdf$factor), function(x) {
       x1 <- mdf[, if(any(factor==x)) .SD, id][, .(factor= x, avg=mean(value))]}))
#   factor      avg
#1:      a 3.333333
#2:      b 3.000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun, perfect. If I'd like to have the average of the ids who did not have a factor, can I write `if(any(factor==x))` for instance, let's say I want to select the ids who did not have b and take average of them

Comment: @MFR In that case, maybe `if(all(factor!= x))`

Answer (score 2):

An idea via base R,

```
fun1 <- function(df, f, include = TRUE){ 
  ind <- unique(df$id[df$factor == f])
  if (include == TRUE) {
  return(mean(df$value[df$id %in% ind]))
  } else {
  return(mean(df$value[!df$id %in% ind])) 
  }
}

sapply(levels(mdf$factor), function(i) fun1(mdf, i))
#       a        b 
#3.333333 3.000000 

sapply(levels(mdf$factor), function(i) fun1(mdf, i, include = FALSE))
#  a   b 
#NaN   5
```